# How I can encode every file (not only bitmaps) to base64?

Tags: android, encoding, base64

I'm looking for a solution of my problem which is connected with encoding files to base64 and sending to my server. I found a solution for encoding bitmaps in the Internet:

```
public static String bitmapToEncodedString(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
```

but this solution can be used only for bitmaps, and what about pdf-files or doc or smth like that. Maybe someone has a good solution for my problem? I will be so pleased if you will give me a solution of my problem.

Comment: Rad file into byte array, and do the same thing as with the `byte[] imageBytes` in your code

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, but how I can rad file into byte array? I have looked for a solution for a long time but each method was unworkable. And I also faced with a statement that this solution will fill ram at me phone, is is true?

Comment: `will fill ram at me phone,` yes, as the byte array is stored in ram. But any case - base64 String will take much more RAM then the original byte array. This way it actually makes no sense to try to encode large files to base64. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: and I don't understand is it good or bad for me? and maybe you have some method for radding file to byte array?

Comment: `Why do you want to do that?` What is your goal?

Comment: I try to create the fulctionality of attaching files to my messages and then sending to my server. It is like a custom e-mail client.

Comment: then you don't have to encode them to base64, you can send them raw

Comment: what you mean in raw?

Comment: raw means without modifying them (converting to base64 string in your case)

Comment: I was said to send base64 string :) I asked about multipart, but base64 is the best as I understood. My server programmers are sure that I have to send in base64.

Comment: then you have a problem where you can't send large files.

Comment: I said them about it)) general size of my attached files is 20mb

Comment: that *probably* would be OK. So you will need 20 MB ram for original byte array + (4 * 20 mb / 3)  mb of memory to store the Base64 encoded string (probably multiplied by 2, or even 4)